# How can I instance linked assets with attached armatures?

Tags: armature, instances

For a short film project I created many assets, each in it's own blend file. Some of the assets contains armatures. I want to link these into the movie scene file, instantiate them multiple times and animate each instance individually.

Is this possible?

Currently I achieved something similar only by duplicating the assets into the scene file which break the ability to update the placeholder assets.

Is there a good workflow?

Greetings

Comment: Hi. This site is no regular forum rather a Q&A site. No need to add [Solved] to the title, accept one of the answers instead, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by trying out and want to share my solution.

Using "Duplicate Linked" is exactly what I was trying to achieve:
[image]

After rename and reparent the linked collection I could individually pose each door:
[image]

The armature, the mesh and all materials are linked to the asset library file and changes are reflected in the movie file.

Hope to help others with same problem :-)
Greetings